# Generating random number of length 6 with SecureRandom in Ruby

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-5, rspec-rails, secure-random

I tried `SecureRandom.random_number(9**6)` but it sometimes returns 5 and sometimes 6 numbers. I'd want it to be a length of 6 consistently. I would also prefer it in the format like `SecureRandom.random_number(9**6)` without using syntax like `6.times.map` so that it's easier to be stubbed in my controller test.

Comment: Hint: `9**6` is 531441.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can do it with math:

```
(SecureRandom.random_number(9e5) + 1e5).to_i
```

Then verify:

```
100000.times.map do
  (SecureRandom.random_number(9e5) + 1e5).to_i
end.map { |v| v.to_s.length }.uniq
# => [6]
```

This produces values in the range 100000..999999:

```
10000000.times.map do
  (SecureRandom.random_number(9e5) + 1e5).to_i
end.minmax
# => [100000, 999999]
```

If you need this in a more concise format, just roll it into a method:

```
def six_digit_rand
  (SecureRandom.random_number(9e5) + 1e5).to_i
end
```

Comment: Thanks, seems like `(SecureRandom.random_number(9e5) + 1e5).to_i` is what I am looking for.

Comment: How to use this for generating random number of length `n`?

Comment: Use `9 * 10**(n-1) ` and `10**(n-1)` instead.

Comment: Getting an error when trying to pass `9e5` as a parameter to random_number, although `10**6` works.

Comment: @MTarantini You can always do it long_form: `1_000_000`.

Comment: This appropriately answers the question as asked, but in case anyone else is looking to generate a six digit code (such as for SMS based MFA) see Eliot Sykes answer below for a more secure and comprehensive answer.

Answer (score 12):

To generate a random, 6-digit string:

```
# This generates a 6-digit string, where the
# minimum possible value is "000000", and the
# maximum possible value is "999999"
SecureRandom.random_number(10**6).to_s.rjust(6, '0')
```

---

Here's more detail of what's happening, shown by breaking the single line into multiple lines with explaining variables:

```
  # Calculate the upper bound for the random number generator
  # upper_bound = 1,000,000
  upper_bound = 10**6

  # n will be an integer with a minimum possible value of 0,
  # and a maximum possible value of 999,999
  n = SecureRandom.random_number(upper_bound)

  # Convert the integer n to a string
  # unpadded_str will be "0" if n == 0
  # unpadded_str will be "999999" if n == 999999
  unpadded_str = n.to_s

  # Pad the string with leading zeroes if it is less than
  # 6 digits long.
  # "0" would be padded to "000000"
  # "123" would be padded to "000123"
  # "999999" would not be padded, and remains unchanged as "999999"
  padded_str = unpadded_str.rjust(6, '0')
```

Answer (score 0):

Docs to [Ruby SecureRand](https://docs.ruby-lang.org/en/2.2.0/SecureRandom.html), lot of cool tricks here.

Specific to this question I would say: `(SecureRandom.random_number * 1000000).to_i`

Docs: `random_number(n=0)`

> If 0 is given or an argument is not given, ::random_number returns a float: 0.0 <= ::random_number < 1.0.

Then multiply by 6 decimal places (`* 1000000`) and truncate the decimals (`.to_i`)

If letters are okay, I prefer `.hex`:

`SecureRandom.hex(3) #=> "e15b05"`

Docs:
`hex(n=nil)`

> ::hex generates a random hexadecimal string.
>
> The argument n specifies the length, in bytes, of the random number to
> be generated. The length of the resulting hexadecimal string is twice
> n.
>
> If n is not specified or is nil, 16 is assumed. It may be larger in
> future.
>
> The result may contain 0-9 and a-f.

Other options:

- `SecureRandom.uuid #=> "3f780c86-6897-457e-9d0b-ef3963fbc0a8"`
- `SecureRandom.urlsafe_base64 #=> "UZLdOkzop70Ddx-IJR0ABg"`

For Rails apps creating a barcode or uid with an object you can do something like this in the object model file:

```
before_create :generate_barcode

  def generate_barcode
    begin
      return if self.barcode.present?
      self.barcode = SecureRandom.hex.upcase
    end while self.class.exists?(barcode: barcode)
  end
```

Answer (score -2):

SecureRandom.random_number(n) gives a random value between 0 to n. You can achieve it using rand function.

```
2.3.1 :025 > rand(10**5..10**6-1)
=> 742840
```

rand(a..b) gives a random number between a and b. Here, you always get a 6 digit random number between 10^5 and 10^6-1.

Comment: Why are you recommending the non-secure `rand` instead? That's really a step backwards.

Comment: Yea agreed, I wouldn't use `rand`, I would stick to `SecureRandom`